# Merge Sort-Segmentation fault

Tags: c, mergesort

I have written a program in C for the Merge Sort but I get a Segmentation Fault and I don't know why? Could you give me a hint what could be wrong?

That's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

  void Merge(int A[],int p,int q,int r){
       int n1,n2,i,j,k;
       n1=q-p+1;
       n2=r-q;
       int L[n1],R[n2];
       for (i=0; i<n1; i++) L[i]=A[p+i-1];
       for (j=0; j<n2; j++) R[j]=A[q+j];
       i=0;
       j=0;
       for (k=p; k<r; k++){
          if (L[i]<=R[j]){
              A[k]=L[i];
              i=i+1;
          }
          else{
          A[k]=R[j];
          j=j+1;
          }
          }
  }

  void Sort(int A[],int p,int r){
      int q;
       if (p<r){
          q=floor((p+r)/2);
          Sort(A,p,q);
          Sort(A,q+1,r);
          Merge(A,p,q,r);
        }
        }  
 int main()
 {
    int n,i,p,r;
    printf("Give a value for n: \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int A[n];
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf ("Give %d th value of the array: \n",i+1 );
        scanf("%d",&A[i]);
    }
    printf("Give me a value for p:\n");
    scanf("%d",&p);
    printf("Give me a value for r:\n");
    scanf("%d",&r);
    Sort(A,p,r);
    printf("p=%d, r=%d \n \n", p,r);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) printf("%d", A[i]);
    return 0;
 }
```

That's what I got,giving inputs at the terminal:

```
Give a value for n:
8
Give 1 th value of the array:
1
Give 2 th value of the array:
6
Give 3 th value of the array:
5
Give 4 th value of the array:
3
Give 5 th value of the array:
5
Give 6 th value of the array:
4
Give 7 th value of the array:
2
Give 8 th value of the array:
7
Give me a value for p:
2
Give me a value for r:
6
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Have I done maybe something wrong at the function Sort?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it to see *where* the crash is?

Comment: Also, take a closer look at this line: `for (j=0; j<n2; j++) R[i]=A[q+j];`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes,it should be R[j],I changed it..but I still get segmentation fault.I have a cygwin editor..How can I make debugging?

Comment: Read about [the GNU debugger](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY What do you mean?

Comment: L or R be depleted is not taken into consideration .

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I found the algorithm of the Merge Sort in my notes and I wanted to implement it in C.. So,have I done something wrong at the function Merge?

Comment: E.g L : [1,2,3], R : [4,5,6], A [] -> L : [], R : [4,5,6], A:[1,2,3] -> `if (L[i]<=R[j]){` is Incorrect reference.

Answer (score 2):

A probable culprit is these two lines:

```
int n1,n2,i,j,k;
int L[n1],R[n2];
```

In the first you declare `n1` and `n2`, but don't initialize them. That means their value is *indeterminate* and that you should not use those variable until you have initialized them.

However, in the next line you use them anyway and that causes [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which means your whole program is ill-formed and can not be relied upon to work properly.

Comment: Now,the Segmentation Fault disappereared!! With the same input as I have written at my first post,I get 16546327.

Although,the result is not right.. So,have I done also an other mistake? :/

Comment: Joachim Shouldn't it be like that:

`int n1,n2,i,j,k`;
      `n1=q-p+1`;
       `n2=r-q;`
       `int L[n1],R[n2];`

so that we have defined n1 and n2,as I have changed it in my initial post?

Answer (score 1):

Your `n1` and `n2` variables in function `Merge` are undefined prior to you instantiating variables `L[]` and `R[]`.

Try this:

```
int n1, n2, i, j, k;

n1 = q - p + 1;
n2 = r - q;

// Now you can instantiate your arrays
int L[n1], R[n2];
```

Comment: Now,the Segmentation Fault disappereared!! With the same input as I have written at my first post,I get 16546327.

Although,the result is not right.. So,have I done also an other mistake? :/

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

void mergesort(int a[],int beg,int end)
{
    int mid;
    if(beg<end)
        mid = (beg+end)/2;
        mergesort(a,beg,mid);
        mergesort(a,mid+1,end);
        merge(a,beg,mid,end);
}

void merge(int a[],int beg,int mid,int end)
{
    int i=beg,j=mid+1,index=beg,temp[100],k;
    while((i<=mid) && (j<=end))
    {
        if(a[i]<a[j])
        {
            temp[index]=a[i];
            i=i+1;
        }
        else
        {
            temp[index]=a[j];
            j++;
        }
        index++;
    }
    if(i>mid)
    {
        while(j<=end)
        {
            temp[index]=a[j];
            j++;
            index++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while(i<=mid)
        {
            temp[index]=a[i];
            i++;
            index++;
        }
    }
    for(k=beg;k<index;k++)
    {
        a[k]=temp[k];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[100],n,i,j;
    printf("enter size of array");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("enter elements");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    mergesort(a,0,n-1);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("5d",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if you explained what you did to fix the code, and how it is different from the existing answers. I edited your post to fix the formatting issues, but left your first `if` as-is. The indentation makes me think you meant to put braces around that block, but I wasn't sure. Please [edit] yourself if that was a typo.